# Monitored training session save all checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow

While using the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, is it possible to save all the checkpoints.
It has a parameter (`save_checkpoint_secs=600`) to specify after how much we want to save a checkpoint but there is no option to specify how many checkpoints you can save.

While using the simple `tf.train.Saver()`, there is an option to specify `max_to_keep`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a `tf.train.Saver` using a `tf.train.Scaffold` to a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(saver=tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10))
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(scaffold=scaffold) as sess:
    ...
```

Comment: `Scaffold` worked for me. For some reason, the `CheckpointSaverHook` did not maintain the correct number of checkpoints. For each run, `CheckpointSaverHook` adds `max_to_keep` number of checkpoints. I define it like so: `tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(
        checkpoint_dir=train_dir,
        save_secs=60,  # checkpoint every 60 secs
        saver=tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=3)
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for coming a bit late on this. If you are using the tf.train.saver you would not specify any saver information from monitored session else all the information from the saver will be overridden